# Is there any APIs that applys the same thing into different views in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view

I have 3 buttons that has the same animation.

let's call them, button1, button2, button3.

```
button1
    .animate()
    .setDuration(initialTime)
    .setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
    .alpha(1f)
    .start()
button2
    .animate()
    .setDuration(initialTime)
    .setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
    .alpha(1f)
    .start()
button3
    .animate()
    .setDuration(initialTime)
    .setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
    .alpha(1f)
    .start()
```

But this is too long. I need something like...

```
with(button1+button2+button3).apply{
    this.animate()
    .setDuration(initialTime)
    .setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
    .alpha(1f)
    .start()
}
```

This will be clearer and simpler.
I could make a list of the views but this method is also longer and massier.

Is there any features like that in Kotlin?

Comment: you could create your own custom button view and have all of these properties set up by default

Comment: This is what functions are for, just extract a function that does the stuff you want on a given view (probably an extension function) and use it repeatedly on different views

Comment: @Joffrey well, I don't think it's a good idea. If the function keeps using here and there, then I might consider.

Answer (score 2):

```
val buttons = listOf(button1, button2, button3)
buttons.forEach { 
    it.animate()
    .setDuration(initialTime)
    .setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
    .alpha(1f)
    .start()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

extension function

```
fun Button.setUp() {
    this.animate()
        .setDuration(initialTime)
        .setInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator())
        .alpha(1f)
        .start()
}
```

```
button1.setUp()
button2.setUp()
button3.setUp()
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good way. I only use Extension function for general ussage. If that function is used in one Activity or something then... I think that's not a good approach.

Comment: I still need to call `setUp()` three times in your example.

Comment: @c-an why do you think so? Do you never use private functions at all? Reusing a piece of code is exactly what functions are for - whether it's in the same file or not is irrelevant. It's also a very nice way to give a name to this unit of work that you're doing, so the reader understands what the point is without having to read it all.

Comment: In this answer, I still need to call setUp() three times. So, it's not the answer that I was looking for.